# FAB hides below listview only in Kitkat

Tags: android, listview, android-4.4-kitkat, floating-action-button

I am using a ListView in my activity which also has a FAB.
In L and above the FAB is displayed properly, but in Kitkat ListView comes on top of FAB, so FAB is not seen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

The content_main has the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_txn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder" />
```

In the studio the FAB is visible properly.

I tried to follow the articles in SO... 
Some articles suggest to use app:layout_anchor, that resulted in **ClassCastException**

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams cannot be
>   cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

I have tried to set `elevation`, `translationZ` **etc**

What needs to be done, any ideas?

Comment: which is the parent layout? (the one cointainint appbatm content and fab)

Comment: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

you could use android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout as your root view

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is used... don't I know why it is not showing up in the question even though I have pasted the full xml there. If you click on edit you will see it.